# jquery uploading several files exceeds post_max_size despite being small enough

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I am getting the following error when uploading 20 files that are all together about 5MB large:

> POST Content-Length of 13820516 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

The limit is correct, since the 'post_max_size' is set to 8M.

**I do not want to change the limits by the way**. I want to find out why I content-length is almost 3 times larger than what I am actually trying to upload.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#uploadForm').submit(function() { // once the form us submitted
    // server limits:
    var max_files = <?php echo ini_get('max_file_uploads'); ?>;
    var max_size = <?php echo unc_tools_bytes_get(ini_get('post_max_size')); ?>;

    var fileInput = jQuery("input[type='file']").get(0);
    var actual_count = parseInt(fileInput.files.length);

    var actual_size = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        var file = fileInput.files[i];
        if ('size' in file) {
            actual_size = actual_size + +file.size;
        }
    }

    // check for max file number

    if (actual_count > max_files) {
        alert("Your webserver allows only a maximum of " + max_files + " files");
        return false;
    }

    if (actual_size > max_size){
        alert("Your webserver allows only a maximum of " + max_size + " Bytes, you tried " + actual_size);
        return false;
    }
    jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  // do ajaxSubmit with the obtions above
    return false; // needs to be false so that the HTML is not actually submitted & reloaded
});
```

The server limits return correctly:

```
var max_files = 20;
var max_size = 8388608;
```

If I take the "if (actual_size > max_size){" away and just let the alert trigger, it even says:

> Your webserver allows only a maximum of 8388608 Bytes, you tried 5841547

I am doing this with jpg files. I tried many different files in different sizes, allways the same when I use 20 files.

upload_max_filesize is 2M, and the files I am trying to upload are each below 1M.

If I try to upload 5M in less but larger files, I do not have that issue.
Any idea why and how can I fix that?

Comment: What about upload_max_filesize?

Comment: @mitkosoft sorry, forgot to mention that, added the info above, does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Are the original files in a compressed state when you try to upload them?

Comment: @korgrue they are jpg files, not sure if you call that compressed?